# Using induction starting from 1 in Coq

Tags: coq, coq-tactic, formal-verification

I am trying to use induction starting from 1 in a Coq proof. From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27205573/coq-induction-start-at-specific-nat) I got a proof of the induction principle I need:

```
Section induction_at_1.
  Variable P : nat -> Prop.
  Hypothesis p1 : P 1.
  Hypothesis pS : forall n, P n -> P (S n).

  Theorem induction_at_1:
    forall n, n > 0 -> P n.

    induction n; intro.
    - exfalso; omega.
    - destruct n.
      + apply p1.
      + assert (S n >= 1) by omega.
        intuition.
  Qed.
End induction_at_1.
```

What I get looks structurally very similar to standard induction. In fact, `Check nat_ind` yields

```
nat_ind:
  forall P : nat -> Prop,
  P 0 ->
  (forall n : nat, P n -> P (S n)) ->
  forall n : nat, P n
```

while `Check induction_at_1` yields

```
induction_at_1:
  forall P : nat -> Prop,
  P 1 ->
  (forall n : nat, P n -> P (S n)) ->
  forall n : nat, n > 0 -> P n
```

The issue arises when I try to apply this induction principle. For instance, I would like to prove by induction

```
Lemma cancellation:
  forall a b c: nat, a > 0 -> a * b = a * c -> b = c.
```

This seems exactly suited to the kind of induction I have above, but when I start my proof like this

```
  intros a b c H0 H1.
  induction a using induction_at_1.
```

I get the following error, which I cannot interpret:

```
Not the right number of induction arguments (expected 2 arguments).
```

Since the two induction principles look almost identical to me, I am not sure why this does not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also find this behavior puzzling, but there are a few ways around it.  One is to use the ssreflect induction tactic, called `elim`:

```
From Coq Require Import ssreflect.

Lemma cancellation:
  forall a b c: nat, a > 0 -> a * b = a * c -> b = c.
Proof.
intros a b c H.
elim/induction_at_1: a / H.
(* ... *)
Abort.
```

The second line is telling Coq to perform induction on `H` (not `a`) while generalizing `a` and using the induction principle `induction_at_1`. I couldn't get something similar to work using the regular Coq `induction`.

An alternative is to use plain natural number induction. In this case, I believe that the lemma follows by induction on `b` while generalizing `c` (I am not sure that induction on `a` works).  If you do need to show something of the form `m <= n -> P n` for all `n`, you can replace `n` by `n - m + m` (which should be possible with the `m <= n` hypothesis), and then prove `P (n - m + m)` by induction on `n - m`.